# Create Solr indexes through CQL/Java Driver with Datastax Enterprise

Tags: solr, cassandra, lucene, datastax-enterprise, stratio

One of the reasons that we are looking at DSE is because of the search and analytics capability it has. However, when I went through the search course it seems that DSE Search (solr) can't be indexed using CQL by defining the columns to be indexed when creating the table, it all needs to be defined by solr core xml and a restart, is this the case?

To be able to create indexed (Lucene index) Cassandra columns programmatically in runtime via CQL is of outermost importance to our business.

Stratio Lucene index plugin for Cassandra has this capability (it seems). Maybe I missed it but, has DSE Search this capability as well?

Answer (score 1):

As of version 4.8, DSE does not support creating search indexes directly via CQL. The easiest way to create a core is to use the dsetool command [create_core](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCreateCoreAuto.html), which will auto-generate a Solr schema and configuration directly from the underlying CQL table schema. This does *not* require a restart.

Comment: Well, that sound great that a restart is not necessary, but how would this perform in a production environment with, lets say, thousands of tables and at least some tables will be reindexed every day this way through a script? What is the indexing performance for solr using the dsetool and is it recommended to do this in production?

Comment: Remember that creating a new core in DSE Search is in some ways like creating a C* secondary index. Once created, all updates to the base table will automatically update the index. Unless you change your schema, you should not have to manually reindex the data out of band. (Note, however, that create_core must be used with the parameter reindex=true to populate the entire index from contents of the base table on core creation.)

Comment: If the new core requires field input and output transformers, will a restart be required to see the jar that contains these transformers?

Comment: @JohnC There is currently no hot-deploy option if you need to add a new JAR to .../resources/solr/lib. A restart will be required for post-startup classpath changes.